# How can one solve this equation in $Z^2$?!

Tags: functional-equations, integral-equations

Ho can one solve the egality $2x+3y=xy$ ?
I have to find a value of $x$ in fonction of $y$ so ? 
I have to add somthing and substrate it 
I added -2xy then $2x(1+y)-3y(1+x)=0$ 
Here im suck 
Can someone help me ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the formula $(x-3)(y-2)$.

Comment: OK we have( x-3)(y-2)=xy-2x-3y+6 So we have to think about (x-3)(y-2)=6 then we have 2*3=6 then x-3=2 so x=5 and y-2=3 so y=5 wow 10+15=25 =5*5 thaaanks siir how did u get it ?!

Comment: Experience.  There are some more solutions too,

Comment: Ueah or x-3=3 so x=6 and y-2=2 so y=4 or x-3=1 so x=4 and y=8 solutions are (6,4) and (4,8) and (9,3) and (5,5)

Comment: Don't forget about negative numbers, for example $(-6)(-1)=6$.